# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory

Tags: java, jsf-2, tomcat7

I am writing a web application using JSF 2. I have downloaded mojarra-2.1.3-FCS-binary.zip and myfaces-core-assembly-2.1.3-bin.zip, and with each library, I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1663)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:591)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:482)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:138)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:959)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:360)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 34 more
```

For Mojarra, I included `javax.faces.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` folder, and for MyFaces, I replace the jar with the following: myfaces-api-2.1.3.jar, myfaces-bundle-2.1.3.jar, myfaces-impl-2.1.3.jar.

I've included jstl-api-1.2.jar as well as jstl-impl-1.2.jar.

And `ApplicationFactory` is found in those jars. What is the issue with JSF in these instances?

I'm using Tomcat 7 to run my web application.

Comment: Have you tried to locate the Libaries under "/apache-tomcat-7/lib" ?

Comment: @Mhh Lecker, the jars mentioned in the question contains the classes. It doesn't "register" when you run the application though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception suggests that the Mojarra API was been loaded from the server-dedicated classloader while the Mojarra/MyFaces impl is loaded from the webapp-dedicated classloader. Remove the Mojarra JARs from `Tomcat/lib`, `JRE/lib`, `JRE/lib/ext` and/or Tomcat common lib and eventually all places in webapp's runtime classpath other than `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: I double checked and the `javax.faces.jar` is only found in my `WEB-INF` folder. I'm running Tomcat 7.0.20.

Comment: `jsf-api.jar`? `javaee.jar`? Come to think about it, do you have any JSF specific/related `<listener>` in `web.xml`? What Servlet version is your `web.xml` root declaration set to?

Comment: Does `jboss-seam.jar` have anything to do with the conflict?

Comment: `jsf-api.jar`, `javaee.jar` is not found in any "system" `lib` folders and Serlvet version is 3.0. and I don't have any listener specified yet.

Comment: Found it. It seems that `jboss-seam.jar` creates a conflict with my application. Thanks BalusC.

Comment: That suggests that it also contains a JSF API library.